C++23 deducing this
Reading new C++ 23 features , I came up to deducing this
Instead of writing the following function signatures to handling rvalue and lvalue
void bar()&&;
void bar()&;

deduce this can be used like the following
 void bar(this A &&);

I except that this A&& follow templates rules and using this I can handle both &,&& but this does not happen
When I try
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public:
    void bar(this A &&)&&{
        std::cout << "bar &&" << std::endl;
    }
};
A foo(){
    return A{};
}
int main() {
   foo().bar();
   auto a = foo();
   a.bar();
}

The following error is generated

:15:4: error: rvalue reference to type 'A' cannot bind to
lvalue of type 'A'    15 |    a.bar();
      |    ^ :5:23: note: passing argument to parameter here
    5 |     void bar(this A &&){
^

https://godbolt.org/z/7Tvqx9hb8
Using template this works as expected
enter link description here
My question is if I cannot use deduce this without template what is the purpose of using deducing without template.For example
void bar(this A & ). 

Since I need to define define again more than one overloading functions for handling cv,rvalue,lvalue e.t.c

the error from the posted code is error: explicit object member function cannot have '&&' qualifier

your first code is simply wrong. You misunderstand how deducing this works. Where did you read that void bar(this A &&)&&{ should work? (or void bar(this A &&){ ?)

"what is the purpose of using deducing without template" Why disallow this "alternative" syntax? which might be clearer than final &.

The only thing special about explicit this is that the function's first parameter is the calling object. It is otherwise identical to a free function. So what you want is this auto&&.

"if I cannot use deduce this without template what is the purpose of using deducing without template" I dont actually understand the question. If you cannot use if wihout a template, then using it without a template has no purpose

void bar(this A &) does not deduce anything. It is simply another syntax for void bar()&.

Please read this blog post about deducing this by Sy Brand: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/

The purpose is that you can write one member function template for l and r value references.

deduce this can be used like the following
void bar(this A &&);


No. Only when calling a template a type is deduced. Consider this example:
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public:
    template <typename Self>
    void bar(this Self&& s) {
        std::forward<Self>(s).foo();
    }
    void foo() && {
        std::cout << "foo &&" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo() & {
        std::cout << "foo &" << std::endl;
    }

};


A foo(){
    return A{};
}
int main() {
   foo().bar();
   auto a = foo();
   a.bar();
}

output:
foo &&
foo &

foo in the example is merely to illustrate that Self is deduced differently in the two calls. The purpose of deducing this is that you need not write two overloads and still can distinguish iniside the function whether the object is a temporary or not.
